# onLocationChanged() not called in Android

Tags: android, location

I'm developing a mini app to detect the current location of the user which i follow on this website http://androidexample.com/GPS_Basic__-__Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=68 . I'm able to change the Lat and Lon in the extended control on the emulator itself. But when comes to using in my Xiaomi 1S (running version 4.2.2) phone it does not show any of my location. Below is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    btnSpoof = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_spoof);
    lblShowLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblShowLat);
    lblShowLon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblShowLon);
    lblShowTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblShowTime);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);



    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }


        });

    Thread t = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                                updateDateTime();

                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();



    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        } else {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    2);

        }
    }

    lblShowLat.setText("No Lat");
    lblShowLon.setText("No Lon");
}


@Override

//code does not run here

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if(location !=null) {

        lblShowLat.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
        lblShowLon.setText(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
        String str = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
        System.out.println("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to find your location, try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Your help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think You forgot to add this line ,

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,10,this);
```

and as well as ensure that device gps and network is enable or not with internet connectivity.

Comment: ok, i have added the line inside the OnCreate method. Yes, all are enabled. But it is still not working

Comment: have you found out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please add these line ..it will work for you .

**Add permission:-**

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

android.permission.INTERNET
```

**In Java.class:-**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

   locationManager = (LocationManager)   getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,     this);
     }

   @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" +       location.getLongitude());
     }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
   {
   Log.d("Latitude","disable");
     }

 @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
   Log.d("Latitude","enable");
    }

  @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  Log.d("Latitude","status");
     }
   }
```